# yum install: "No package <package-name> available": fedora.repo empty

Tags: fedora, yum

I am using Fedora 17 and I cannot install packages using `yum`. I get this error:

```
[root@cousinot ~]# yum install fedup
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
medInria                                                 |  951 B     00:00     
medInria/primary                                           | 3.6 kB   00:00     
medInria                                                                    3/3
No package fedup available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

And I get the same error **with all packages**. In the /etc/yum.repos.d/ I have:

```
[root@cousinot yum.repos.d]# ls
fedora.repo                  rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo
fedora-updates.repo          rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide.repo
fedora-updates-testing.repo  rpmfusion-nonfree.repo
medInria.repo                rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo
rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo  rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing.repo
rpmfusion-free.repo          yumconf-sop
rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
```

But: `vim fedora.repo` shows an empty file. `fedora-updates.repo` and `fedora-updates-testing.repo` are also empty.

I tried `yum update`: it gives `No packages marked for update`.

I tried to reinstall Fedora 17 to get the repo files back. Both `rpm -Uvh` with `--oldpackage` or `--replacepkgs` did not work (it gives: `package fedora-release-17-2.noarch is already installed`). But `yum reinstall` reinstalled it successfully.

However, even after reinstallation, the repo files are still empty and I can still not install packages using yum (same error as before with `fedup`, see above).

What can I do? For example, could I just copy-paste in these files what should be written? Many thanks again for your help...

Comment: Did you try `yum update`?

Comment: Yes, I get "No packages marked for update." And it does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the fedora-release package from any mirror and reinstall it. That should get your repo files back.

For example

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/f/fedora-release-17-1.noarch.rpm
```

You would just need to know which version of Fedora you have to get the right repo.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. As I have x86_64, I run this but I got this error: `[root@cousinot ~]# rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/f/fedora-release-17-1.noarch.rpm
Retrieving https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/f/fedora-release-17-1.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
 package fedora-release-17-2.noarch (which is newer than fedora-release-17-1.noarch) is already installed
`

Comment: @Nina I think adding `--oldpackage` will allow that to continue. You could also use `yum reinstall` instead of `rpm -Uvh` — the direct URL should work even if the repos are corrupted.

Comment: Many thanks for you answer. Yes, I have tried `--oldpackage` and also `--replacepkgs` but it did not change anything. While running them, I still get: `package fedora-release-17-2.noarch is already installed`. However, `yum reinstall` reinstalled it (thank you). But the repo files are still corrupted (read: empty) and I still cannot run `yum install fedup`, which was my first purpose. What can I do? many thanks again.

Comment: It may be that it wont install because it was older.  Try this reinstall: ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/archive.fedoraproject.org/fedora/linux/updates/17/i386/fedora-release-17-2.noarch.rpm

Comment: or even just "yum reinstall fedora-release"

Answer (score 0):

Another way I'm thinking that might work comes from http://fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=271496

Wherein the solution suggested was to manually update fedora.repo with

```
[fedora]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch

[fedora-debuginfo]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch - Debug
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/debug/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-debug-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch

[fedora-source]
name=Fedora $releasever - Source
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/source/SRPMS/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-source-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch
```

Worth a shot right?  With the variables for version maybe that would work, then again I think version 17's pretty old.